# Save input from one program

Tags: c, io, io-redirection

I have a program idea which is comprised of two parts:

1. I would like to keep track of the input to one program and save the input to a file
2. Then feed the saved input back into the program later. (I have this accomplished)

Simple input program: 
**testProgram.c**

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 int main() {
  3   char str[100];
  4   int i;
  5 
  6   printf("Enter a value : ");
  7   scanf("%s %d", str, &i);
  8 
  9   printf("\nYou entered: %s %d\n", str, i);
 10   
 11   return 0;
 12 }
```

How would I save the input from one program to a file (or program)?

**EDIT** Sorry my question is very unclear. I see now how it could be perceived in different ways. I should have been more clear with what I was asking.

David's summary of my question: "How do I take user input and then write the questions and the answer to a file at the beginning of my program that I can later then read back into my program from the file?"" is true, except I don't care to keep the questions, just the answers (i.e., the input). I also would like it **general purpose** and to **not alter the program I want to receive the input from**. This means I can grab the input a user enters into **any** program, **without changing any code**.

**Ideal behavior**
If I ran the above program with input `hello` and `1`, the terminal should produce:

```
Enter a value : hello 
1

You entered: hello 1
```

These inputs should be recorded in an **outputFile** of the input (confusing, I know) to the previous program. This file would look like:

```
hello
3
```

Comment: Are you aware of the tool `tee` ? You can use it to write its own input into a file AND write it to output, which you can then pipe into your own progeam. That way the input to  your program ends up in a file, too. ( I partially ask this to make you elaborate on what you actually want to achieve. You seem not to want to simply write the input to a file from your own program, which would be a topic for working through the most basic file operation tutorial.)

Comment: When saying "three parts", making an enumeration of only 1 and 2 is irritating....

Comment: Wow, I was not aware of this tool. This is ALMOST what I want. I still want the ability for the user to see the prompts from stdout as it is passed to the file (e.g., `Enter a value`). If I do `./a.out | tee file2.txt`, there is a delay in the prompts (they spit out at the end) and the prompts get spat out to a file, whereas I ONLY want the input. Perhaps I could use it in conjunction with another tool or in some way I am not thinking to make this a reality? Edit: Sorry, that's a leftover from an edit -- thanks for the catch.

Comment: I think that means that you are referring to the OUTPUT of your program, not the INPUT to it.

Comment: Sorry, I currently do not have tee myself. Did you try `tee file2.txt | ./a.out` ? Not sure whether it works this way and could not try....

Comment: @DanielConnelly It is still unclear what you want to achieve. In your C program, you open an output file for writing with `FILE *fp = fopen ("somefile", "w");` and then check `if (fp == NULL) { perror ("fopen-somefile"); return 1 }` to validate the file is open for writing. Then you simply write to it with `fputs` or `fprintf` or `fputc`, etc... You can write your prompts there if you like as well (or use `freopen` to redirect one of the standard streams to it). If you then need to read what you have written, `fclose` the file an open it for reading.

Comment: **Edit: I had a typo where I said output rather than input** I appreciate the help. I MYSELF want to SAVE the INPUT to file `testProgram.c` while I want the USER to SEE the OUTPUT (seeing the input too would be nice) from file `testProgram.c`. The output of `tee file2.txt | ./a.out` is strangely the same as `./a.out | tee file2.txt`.

Comment: `tee` is more a shell utility and it isn't what you want for an interactive program. You user WILL see your prompt AND their input (which will be written to the file) They see their input by default due to the terminal echo of the characters they type. Your job before writing is to capture than input in a variable (or array, etc...) and then you write the contents of whatever variable or array to your file as output.

Comment: Normally that is true. In combination with `./a.out` though, a user can't see any output until the very end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I get from your comments, the question you are asking is "How do I take user input and then write the questions and the answer to a file at the beginning of my program that I can later then read back into my program from the file?"

Despite the obvious that you should maintain the data in memory in a usable form to avoid the file I/O, there is learning to be had in how to use a file in this way. You have a couple of options, you can either open the file in `"rw"` (read/write) mode and use `rewind()`, `lseek()` or `fgetpos()/fsetpos()` to move the file position indicator around as needed, a more basic way is simply to open the file in `"w"` write mode for writing, write what you need to the file, `fclose()` the file and then open the file in `"r"` read mode and read the data back in.

Let's look at the basic case and see if that is what you are looking for. To open a file for writing you simply provide a filename to `fopen()` and then validate that your file was in fact open and is ready for use, e.g. using the filename provided in the first argument to the program, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC], pet[MAXC];  /* read buffer, and buffer to store pet */
    FILE *fp = NULL;            /* FILE* pointer to hold open file stream */

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate at least 1 argument given */
        fprintf (stderr, "usage: %s outfilename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* validate file open for writing */
    if ((fp = fopen (argv[1], "w")) == NULL) {
        perror ("file open for write failed");
        return 1;
    }
```

Next you will prompt the user for whatever information your want and then read his response into `buf` using `fgets()` (don't forget all line-oriented input function read and store the `'\n'` in the buffer they fill), e.g.

```
    fputs ("type of pet?: ", stdout);   /* prompt user */
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {    /* read/validate input */
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;        /* trim trailing '\n' from buf */
    strcpy (pet, buf);                  /* copy pet from buf to pet */
```

Now you have read the user input, and trimmed the trailing `'\n'` using `strcspn()`, you are ready to write your first question and answer to the file, e.g.

```
    fprintf (fp, "type of pet?: %s\n", pet);    /* write Q & A to file */
```

Repeat the prompt, read, trim and output to file for as many inputs as you have, e.g.

```
    /* prompt user with 2nd question */
    fprintf (stdout, "your %s (\"has fleas\"/\"has no fleas\")? ", pet);
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {    /* read/validate input */
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;        /* trim trailing '\n' from buf */

    fprintf (fp, "your %s %s\n", pet, buf);     /* write Q & A to file */
```

Now close the file you have been writing to:

```
    if (fclose (fp))    /* always validate close after writing to file */
        perror ("fclose");
```

Next, open the file for reading and read all lines of data stored in the file and output the lines to `stdout` so you can confirm what you have written:

```
    if ((fp = fopen (argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {  /* open/validate for reading */
        perror ("file open for read failed");
        return 1;
    }

    fputs ("\ndata written to file:\n\n", stdout);  /* write heading */
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp))   /* read/validate each line from file */
        fputs (buf, stdout);        /* print it to stdout */

    fclose (fp);    /* simply close file after reading */

    return 0;
}
```

That's the basic approach. Compile it and give it a try:

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rdstdin_wrtfile dat/petfile.txt
type of pet?: dog
your dog ("has fleas"/"has no fleas")? has fleas

data written to file:

type of pet?: dog
your dog has fleas
```

Check the file contents itself from the shell:

```
$ cat dat/petfile.txt
type of pet?: dog
your dog has fleas
```

So there is not much to it, but the key is to ***validate*** every input and output by checking the return. That is the only way you can have any confidence that your operation completed successfully. Let me know if this was what you were asking or if I missed the intent of your question. I'm happy to help further.

Comment: I wasn't originally clear with my question, but this is a good answer for what my question appeared to be. This could be useful one day. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the program, by default three files will be created such as

```
standard_input [file descriptor = 0 && File pointer = stdin]
standard_output [file descriptor = 1 && File pointer = stdout]
standard_error [file descriptor = 2 && File pointer = stderr]
```

To accomplish the **first step**: flush the content in the standard input file before you take the input from the user.

**Before exiting the program, move the file pointer to the initial position and copy all the contents of the standard input file to "input.txt".**

**second step:**
Later to feed the input to the program from the "input.txt" you can change the default file descriptors and file pointers of the program by using the function `freopen()`

Let say the file "intput.txt" file contains the input.

```
freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
```

Now **stdin** is being pointed to "**input.txt**"
By default, scanf will read from the file pointed by stdin.

Try the below program :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    int i;
    printf("Enter a value : ");
    freopen("input.txt", "r",stdin);
    scanf("%s %d", str, &i);
    printf("\nYou entered: %s %d\n", str, i);
    return 0; 
}
```

Hope the above answer will help you.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but how may I get the contents of the stdin file?